# LUA Script - Duplicating records using multiple delimited category fields

Tags: lua

Looking for help  with a LUA script to duplicate records in a table when there are delimited records in multiple cells

Sample data:

| Product Number | Category Name | Cat Order code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Category Name One,Category Name Two | 3,4 |
| 2 | Category Name Three, Category Name 4 | 2,1 |

This is how I need it to look:

| Product Number | Category Name | Cat Order Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Category Name One | 3 |
| 1 | Category Name Two | 4 |
| 2 | Category Name Three | 2 |
| 2 | Category Name Four | 1 |

Here is the code I am working from which only duplicates the rows but does not delimit the cat order code to the correct rows:

```
for i = 1,records:size() do
    -- Get record i
    record = records:getrecord(i);

    -- Get the contents of the Category field
    categoryField = record:field("Category Name"):content();

    -- Define a duplicates created counted
    n = 0;

    -- For each delimited value
    for k, v in string.gmatch(categoryField , "([^,]+)") do
        if (n == 0) then
        -- Remember the first value
            rememberMe = k;
        else
            -- For anything other than the first, duplicate the record
            newRecord = records:duplicaterecord(i);

            -- Define a unique key
            newRecord:field("Product number"):setcontent( newRecord:field("Product number"):content() .. "-" .. n);

            -- Set the new Category content
            newRecord:field("Category Name"):setcontent(k);
        end
        n = n + 1;
    end
    if n > 1 then
        -- If more than one duplicate was created, set the first value
        record:field("Category Name"):setcontent(rememberMe);
    end
end
```

Comment: Does `records:duplicaterecord(i);` create a new record at the end of the whole list `records`?  Or it may insert the new record in the middle?

Comment: End is fine as it will be sorted after script is ran